# Is it possible to say in Regex "if the next word does not match this expression"?

Tags: regex

I'm trying to detect occurrences of words italicized with `*asterisks*` around it. However I want to ensure it's not within a link. So it should find "text" in `here is some *text*` but not within `http://google.com/hereissome*text*intheurl`.

My first instinct was to use look aheads, but it doesn't seem to work if I use a URL regex such as John Gruber's:

```
(?i)\b((?:[a-z][\w-]+:(?:/{1,3}|[a-z0-9%])|www\d{0,3}[.]|[a-z0-9.\-]+[.][a-z]{2,4}/)(?:[^\s()<>]+|\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\))+(?:\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\)|[^\s`!()\[\]{};:'".,<>?«»“”‘’]))
```

And put it in a look ahead at the beginning of the pattern, followed by the rest of the pattern.

```
(?=URLPATTERN)\*[a-zA-Z\s]\*
```

So how would I do this?

Comment: What's a forward reference? Do you mean lookahead?

Comment: @Barmar Yes, I do, sorry. Fixed.

Comment: What regex flavor are you using?

Comment: @anubhava Objective-C/Swift/Cocoa's.

Comment: @anubhava I'm really not sure and my searches aren't turning up very fruitful.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this alternation technique to match everything first on LHS that you want to discard. Then on RHS use captured group to match desired text.

```
https?:\/\/\S*|(\*\S+\*)
```

You can then use captured group #1 for your emphasized text.

#### [RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/cL6oX3/1)

Comment: Could you explain what this Regex is doing? It looks really fascinating but I'm confused as to what it's doing.

Comment: Yes as I wrote briefly that this regex first matches all the links on LHS of `|`. To detect a link it uses `https://` or `http://` as starting point and matches all non-space character using `\S*` after that. On RHS of `|` we have emphasized text in captured group. **You just need to use captured group #1 for emphasized text.**

Answer (score 0):

The following regexp:

```
^(?!http://google.com/hereissome.*text.*intheurl).*
```

Matches everything but `http://google.com/hereissome*text*intheurl`. This is called negative lookahead. Some regexp libraries may not support it, python's does.

Here is a link to [Mastering Lookahead and Lookbehind](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html).